# How to get babel's language shorthands work inside biblatex entries with autolang=hyphen and langid fields?

Tags: biblatex, babel

I'm writing a German document, where I frequently cite works in English and other languages. Used to `babel`’s shorthands in `ngerman` for easily modifying hyphenation symbols in compound words or names (for example `"=` for an additional hyphen that should always be printed, and `""` for a possible line break without a hyphen), I also activated those shorthands for `english` using the `\addto\extrasenglish` commands.

Inside `otherlanguage` environments in the main document’s text, everything works as expected.

`biblatex`, which I use for managing my bibliographies, offers the `autolang` option and the `langid` field for switching hyphenation rules for each bibliographic entry. When I set `autolang` to `other`, it puts an `otherlanguage` environment around the citations and bibliography entries, and therefore uses the shorthands. But it then also prints terms like `and` in English, which is not desireable in an overall German document. `biblatex` therefore offers the `autolang=hyphen` option to *only activate the hyphenation rules* for the language specified in the `langid` field, while falling back to the main document language for all other terms.

However, then the shorthands do not work anymore. How do I get them to work?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{\useshorthands{"}\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=hyphen,style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@collection{NMR,
  editor = {Wardrip"=Fruin, Noah and Montfort, Nick},
  title = {The New Media Reader},
  location = {Cambridge/""MA and London},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  year = 2003,
  langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
  Manually using babel shorthands inside an \texttt{otherlanguage}
  environment, everything works as expected: Wardrip"=Fruin.
  Cambridge/""MA.
\end{otherlanguage}

Yet, citing the work from the bibliography, where it was given a
\texttt{langid} field, the shorthands do not work.\autocite{NMR}

Neither do they work in the bibliography:
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here - if you put langid=english in a bib entry, it will use "and" as this overrides the global lang setting.

Comment: Only, if you give the `autolang=other` package option. Using the package option `autolang=hyphen` is exactly for using foreign hyphenrules for the actual field contents, but keeping terms like "and" or date formats in the main document language (i.e. *don't translate them*).

Comment: See below answer - this is due the behaviour of babel's hyphenrule environment which disables shorthands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hyphenrules environment actively deactivate all language shorthands. But babel offers generic commands which always work:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{\useshorthands{"}\languageshorthands{ngerman}}


\begin{document}

\begin{hyphenrules}{ngerman}
  Manually using babel shorthands inside an \texttt{hyphenrules}
  environment, doesn't: Wardrip"=Fruin.
  Cambridge/""MA.

  Use the babel commands: Wardrip\babelhyphen{hard}Fruin.
  Cambridge/\babelhyphen{empty}MA.
\end{hyphenrules}
\end{document}
```

[image]

biblatex has also the commands `\hyphen` and `\hyphenate` (but imho nothing for `""`).

## Edit

Actually you can define the shortcut so that they work for all languages:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand{""}{\babelhyphen{empty}}
\defineshorthand{"=}{\babelhyphen{hard}}

\begin{document}
\begin{hyphenrules}{ngerman}
  Wardrip"=Fruin.
  Cambridge/""MA.

  \end{hyphenrules}

\selectlanguage{english}
  Wardrip"=Fruin.
  Cambridge/""MA.

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
  Wardrip"=Fruin.
  Cambridge/""MA.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the time being, I will take this as a valid workaround. But why aren't babel language shorthands not valid inside `hyphenrules` environments? What is the rationale here? Can they be activated somehow?

Comment: Well you can't activate language dependant shortcuts in hyphenrules, but you can create language independant shortcuts. I edited the answer.