# German quote shorthands from babel for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, babel

I try to get `""` from `babel` to work with `biblatex`. [How to get babel's language shorthands work inside biblatex entries with autolang=hyphen and langid fields?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292601/how-to-get-babels-language-shorthands-work-inside-biblatex-entries-with-autolan) explains the general problem, but the solution does not work for me. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbib]{biblatex}

\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
%\useshorthands*{"} 
%\addto\extrasenglish{\useshorthands{"}\languageshorthands{german}}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand{""}{\babelhyphen{empty}}
\defineshorthand{"=}{\babelhyphen{hard}}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
@article{BPYC2011a,
        Author = {Robert C. Berwick and Paul Pietroski and Beracah Yankama and Noam Chomsky},
        Journal = {Cognitive Science},
        Number = {7},
        Pages = {1207--1242},
        Title = {{Poverty of the Stimulus} Hallo/""Halli Revisited},
        Volume = {35},
        Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{SM}

\title{Doing bibliographies with the stars}

\begin{document}

Hallo/""Halli \citep{BPYC2011a} haben gezeigt, dass \ldots.


\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,notkeyword=this]
\end{document}
```

The shortcuts work in the main text but not in the references:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should load biblatex later. The shorthands are activated at \begin{document}, and the bib-entries are read there too, so the order matters:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
%\useshorthands*{"}
%\addto\extrasenglish{\useshorthands{"}\languageshorthands{german}}

\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand{""}{\babelhyphen{empty}}
\defineshorthand{"=}{\babelhyphen{hard}}

\usepackage[natbib]{biblatex}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
@article{BPYC2011a,
        Author = {Robert C. Berwick and Paul Pietroski and Beracah Yankama and Noam Chomsky},
        Journal = {Cognitive Science},
        Number = {7},
        Pages = {1207--1242},
        Title = {{Poverty of the Stimulus} Hallo/""Halli Revisited},
        Volume = {35},
        Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{SM}

\title{Doing bibliographies with the stars}

\begin{document}

Hallo/""Halli \citep{BPYC2011a} haben gezeigt, dass \ldots.


\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,notkeyword=this]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

with the class langscibook mentioned in the comment one can reverse the loading order like this:

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\AfterClass{scrbook}{%
  \RequirePackage[german,english]{babel}%
  \useshorthands*{"}
  \defineshorthand{""}{\babelhyphen{empty}}
  \defineshorthand{"=}{\babelhyphen{hard}}}
\documentclass[biblatexbackend=biber]{langscibook}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
@article{BPYC2011a,
        Author = {Robert C. Berwick and Paul Pietroski and Beracah Yankama and Noam Chomsky},
        Journal = {Cognitive Science},
        Number = {7},
        Pages = {1207--1242},
        Title = {{Poverty of the Stimulus} Hallo/""Halli Revisited},
        Volume = {35},
        Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{SM.bib}

\title{Doing bibliographies with the stars}

\begin{document}

Hallo/""Halli \citep{BPYC2011a} haben gezeigt, dass \ldots.


\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,notkeyword=this]
\end{document}
```

But it would be better if the class would load babel earlier. Lots of packages like to detect the language ....

Comment: Thanks! I use a class from the publisher that already has biblatex loaded. Is there anything I could do in this situation?

Comment: Difficult to say without the class. does it at least load babel before biblatex?

Comment: It is the langsci class: https://ctan.org/pkg/langsci It loads babel with options I do not want, so I prevent the class from loading babel and load it myself. Since the class loads biblatex it is loaded before babel.

Comment: I added an edit.